# Wrong result with moving average cross over

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following values. I want to dedect dates, when the Low is crossing below the SMA8Low.

```
  df['SMA10High'] = df.loc[:,'High'].rolling(window=10).mean()
  df['SMA8Low'] = df.loc[:,'Low'].rolling(window=8).mean()
  df['yesterday'] = df['Low'].shift(1) >= df['SMA8Low'].shift(1) #yesterdays 
  LOW >= SMA8Low
  df['today'] = df['Low'] <= df['SMA8Low']  #Todays Low <= SMA8Low
  df.dropna(inplace=True) #droping NaN values
```

Dataframe result after the above code is the following:

[image: Dataframe]

Now the new column crossing should only be True, if yesterday is true and today is true.

I tried the following code:

```
df['crossover'] = np.where(df['yesterday'] == df['today'],True,False)
#df['crossover'] = np.where(df['today'] & (df['yesterday'] == 
df['today']),True,True)
```

[image]

But the result is wrong. Only the following dates should be True in the column crossover:
2021-01-08 and 2021-01-22

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition to `np.where`:

```
df['crossover'] = np.where(df['today'] & (df['yesterday'] == df['today']),True,True)
```

Comment: I get not the rigth result. I have updated the text.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:
df['crossover'] = np.where(df['today'] & (df['yesterday'] == df['today']),True,False)

```
df['SMA10High'] = df.loc[:,'High'].rolling(window=10).mean()
df['SMA8Low'] = df.loc[:,'Low'].rolling(window=8).mean()
df['yesterday'] = df['Low'].shift(1) >= df['SMA8Low'].shift(1) #yesterdays LOW >= 
SMA8Low
df['today'] = df['Low'] <= df['SMA8Low']  #Todays Low <= SMA8Low
df.dropna(inplace=True) #droping NaN values
df['crossover'] = np.where(df['today'] & (df['yesterday'] == df['today']),True,False)
```